# How can I fix no solution (infeasible) error in Cplex

Tags: python, model, cplex

Is there something wrong with my model? I tried to run the model but it still failed to give me a solution after hours of run time. Thank you so much in advance!

The objective is the minimization of total cost. The model still run but it only show the data that I plug in, and no solution
My mod. file:

```
 // INDEX

int numinbound=...;
int numoutbound=...;
int numreceiving=...;
int numshipping=...;
int numproduct=...;
range inboundtruck=1..numinbound;       //inboundtruck i and m
range outboundtruck=1..numoutbound;     //outboundtruck j and n
range receivingdock=1..numreceiving;    //receivingdock k
range shippingdock=1..numshipping;      //shippingdock l
range producttype = 1..numproduct;      //producttype p
// DATA & PARAMATER
float T[receivingdock][shippingdock]=...;       //Time to transfer one product from a receiving dock k to the outbound truck requesting the product in shipping dock l
float U[receivingdock][producttype]=...;        //Time to transfer one product from a receiving dock k to the corresponding storage zone p
float V[producttype][shippingdock]=...;         //Time to transfer one product from a storage zone p to the outbound truck requesting the product in shipping dock l
float Q[inboundtruck][producttype]=...;             //The amount of products type p to unload by inbound truck i
float R[outboundtruck][producttype]=...;        //The amount of products type p requested by outbound truck j
float A[inboundtruck]=...;                  //Arrival time of inbound truck i
float B[inboundtruck]=...;                  //Expected departure time of inbound truck i
float C[outboundtruck]=...;                 //Arrival time of outbound truck j
float D[outboundtruck]=...;                 //Expected departure time of outbound truck j
int L=2;                                    //Time to load or unload one product
int E=3;                                    //Truck changeover time
float M=1000000;                                //A large positive number
//CONTINUOS DECISION VARIABLES
dvar float+ r[inboundtruck];        //Start time of unloading inbound truck i
dvar float+ e[inboundtruck];        //End time of unloading inbound truck i
dvar float+ s[outboundtruck];       //Start time of loading outbound truck j
dvar float+ f[outboundtruck];       //End time of loading outbound truck j
dvar float+ t[inboundtruck];        //Tardiness of inbound truck i
dvar float+ u[outboundtruck];       //Tardiness of outbound truck j
dvar float+ d[inboundtruck];        //End time of transferring products directly from inbound truck i
dvar float+ g[inboundtruck];        //End time of storing products from inbound truck i
//INTEGER DECISION VARIABLES
dvar int+ alpha[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][producttype];                  //The amount of products type p to transfer directly from inbound truck i to outbound truck j 
dvar int+ beta[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][producttype];                   //The amount of products type p stored by inbound truck i and transferred later to an outbound truck j from storage zone p
dvar int+ eta[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][receivingdock][shippingdock];    //Number of products to transfer from inbound truck i to outbound truck j if inbound truck i is assigned to dock k and outbound truck j is assigned to dock l
dvar int+ lamda[inboundtruck][receivingdock][producttype];                  //Number of products to transfer from inbound truck i to storage zone p if inbound truck i is assigned to dock k
dvar int+ muy[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][shippingdock][producttype];      //Number of products to transfer from storage zone p to the outbound truck j if outbound truck j is assigned to dock l
//BINARY DECISION VARIABLES
dvar boolean v[inboundtruck][outboundtruck];                                //1, if any product transferred directly from inbound truck i to outbound t uck j (aijp > 0); 0, otherwise
dvar boolean w[inboundtruck][producttype];                                  //1, if any product transferred from inbound truck i to storage zone p; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean tau[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][producttype];                 //1, if any product transferred from storage zone p to outbound truck j; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean x[inboundtruck][receivingdock];                                //1, if inbound truck i is assigned to receiving dock k; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean y[outboundtruck][shippingdock];                                //1, if outbound truck j is assigned to shipping dock l; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean p[i in inboundtruck][m in inboundtruck];                       //1, if inbound trucksi and m are assigned to the same receiving dock and i precedes m; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean q[j in outboundtruck][n in outboundtruck];                     //1, if outbound trucks j and n are assigned to the same shipping dock and j precedes n; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean z[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][receivingdock][shippingdock];   //1, if inbound truck i is assigned to dock k and outbound truck j is assigned to dock l and vij = 1; 0,otherwise
dvar boolean delta[inboundtruck][receivingdock][producttype];               //1, if inbound truck i is assigned to dock k and wip =1; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean gamma[inboundtruck][outboundtruck][shippingdock][producttype]; //1, if inbound truck i is assigned to dock k and wip = 1; 0, otherwise
dvar boolean sigma[inboundtruck];                                           //1, if inbound truck i stored at least one product; 0, otherwise
// OBLJECTIVE FUNCTION  
dexpr float W = sum(i in inboundtruck) (e[i]-B[i]) + sum(j in outboundtruck) (f[j]-D[j]);
minimize W;
subject to {
forall(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype)
        sum(j in outboundtruck) (alpha[i][j][p]+beta[i][j][p]) == Q[i][p]; //(1)
//forall(j in outboundtruck, p in producttype)  
        //sum(i in inboundtruck) (alpha[i][j][p]+beta[i][j][p]) == R[j][p]; //(2)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        v[i][j]<= M*sum(p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p]; //(3)
forall(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype)
    w[i][p]<= M*sum(j in outboundtruck) beta[i][j][p]; //(4)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype)
        tau[i][j][p]<= M*beta[i][j][p]; //(5)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        sum(k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock) eta[i][j][k][l]== sum(p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p]; //(6)
forall(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype)
        sum(k in receivingdock) lamda[i][k][p]==sum(j in outboundtruck) beta[i][j][p]; //(7)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype)
        sum(l in shippingdock) muy[i][j][l][p]== beta[i][j][p]; //(8)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock)
         eta[i][j][k][l]<= z[i][j][k][l]*M; //(9)
forall(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype, k in receivingdock)       
        lamda[i][k][p]<= delta[i][k][p]*M; //(10)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype, l in shippingdock)  
        muy[i][j][l][p]<= gamma[i][j][l][p]*M; //(11)
    //TRUCKS ASSIGNMENTS AND SEQUENCING CONSTRAINTS
forall(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype)
        sum(k in receivingdock) delta[i][k][p]== w[i][p]; //(12)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype)
        sum(l in shippingdock) gamma[i][j][l][p]== tau[i][j][p]; //(13)
forall(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype, k in receivingdock)
        delta[i][k][p]<= x[i][k]; //(14)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype, l in shippingdock)
         gamma[i][j][l][p]<= y[j][l]; //(15)
forall(i in inboundtruck)
        sum(k in receivingdock) x[i][k]== 1; //(16)
forall(j in outboundtruck)
        sum(l in shippingdock) y[j][l]== 1; //(17)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        sum(k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock) z[i][j][k][l]== v[i][j]; //(18)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock)
         z[i][j][k][l]<= x[i][k]; //(19) 
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock)
         z[i][j][k][l]<= y[j][l]; //(20)
forall(i in inboundtruck, m in inboundtruck: m!=i, k in receivingdock)       
        x[i][k] + x[m][k] - 1<= p[i][m] + p[m][i]; //(21)
forall(i in inboundtruck, m in inboundtruck: m!=i)
        p[i][m] + p[m][i]<= 1; //(22)
forall(j in outboundtruck, n in outboundtruck: n!=j, l in shippingdock)
       y[j][l]+y[n][l]-1<= q[j][n]+q[n][j]; //(23)
forall(j in outboundtruck, n in outboundtruck: n!=j)
        q[j][n]+q[n][j]<= 1; //(24)
forall(i in inboundtruck)
    sum(m in inboundtruck: m!=i) p[i][m]<= 1; //(25)
forall(j in outboundtruck)
    sum(n in outboundtruck: n!=j) q[j][n]<= 1; //(26)
    //SCHEDULING CONSTRAINT
forall(i in inboundtruck)
        r[i]>= A[i]; //(27)
forall(i in inboundtruck, m in inboundtruck: m!=i)
        r[m]>= e[i] + E - M*(1-p[i][m]); //(28)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)               
        v[i][j]<= (e[i]-s[j])*M;  //(29)  
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        d[i]>= r[i]+L*sum(j in outboundtruck, p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + L*sum(p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + 2*sum(k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock) T[k][l]*eta[i][j][k][l]; //(30)
forall(i in inboundtruck)
        g[i]>= d[i] + 2*L*sum(j in outboundtruck,p in producttype) beta[i][j][p] + 2*sum(k in receivingdock, p in producttype) U[k][p]*lamda[i][k][p] - M*(1-sigma[i]);  //(31)
forall(i in inboundtruck)
        sigma[i]<= M*sum(j in outboundtruck, p in producttype) beta[i][j][p]; //(32)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype)
       s[j]>= g[i] - M*(1-tau[i][j][p]); //(33)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        e[i]>= r[i] + L*sum(j in outboundtruck, p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + L*sum(p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + 2*sum(k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock) T[k][l]*eta[i][j][k][l] + 2*L*sum(j in outboundtruck, p in producttype) beta[i][j][p] + 2*sum(k in receivingdock, p in producttype) U[k][p]*lamda[i][k][p]; //(34)
forall(j in outboundtruck)
        s[j]>= C[j]; //(35)
forall(j in outboundtruck, n in outboundtruck: n!=j)
        s[n]>= f[j] + E - M*(1-q[j][n]); //(36)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        s[j]>= r[i] - M*(1 -v[i][j]); //(37)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck)
        f[j]>= r[i] + L*sum(p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + L*sum(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + L*sum(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype) beta[i][j][p] + 2*sum(k in receivingdock, l in shippingdock) T[k][l]*eta[i][j][k][l] - M*(1-v[i][j]);  //(38)         
forall(j in outboundtruck)
        f[j]>= s[j] + L*(sum(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype) alpha[i][j][p] + sum(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype) beta[i][j][p]);  //(39)
forall(i in inboundtruck, j in outboundtruck, p in producttype)
        f[j]>= s[j] + L*sum(p in producttype) beta[i][j][p] + L*sum(i in inboundtruck, p in producttype) beta[i][j][p] + 2*sum(l in shippingdock) V[p][l]*muy[i][j][l][p]; //(40)

}
```

this is my dat.

```
numinbound=25;
numoutbound=20;
numreceiving=8;
numshipping=10;
numproduct=5;

T   =     [[14, 17, 27, 20, 20, 20, 15, 18, 17, 20],
           [16, 15, 26, 23, 17, 17, 26, 26, 18, 20],
           [17, 21, 27, 25, 18, 21, 27, 27, 19, 20],
           [18, 24, 28, 26, 20, 23, 28, 28, 20, 21],
           [19, 25, 29, 27, 21, 24, 29, 29, 21, 22],
           [20, 26, 30, 28, 22, 25, 30, 30, 22, 23],
           [15, 21, 28, 27, 23, 26, 28, 28, 24, 25],
           [16, 22, 29, 28, 24, 27, 29, 29, 25, 26]];
                                        
U = [[ 9,  5,  7,  6, 10],
     [ 8,  9,  8,  9,  6],
     [ 9,  6, 10,  8,  5],
     [ 8, 10, 10,  5,  7],
     [ 8,  9,  9,  9,  7],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  5,  5],
     [ 8,  7,  8,  7,  5],
     [ 7,  7, 10,  8,  8]];     
V = [[8,   9,  7,  8,  9,  6,  13,  10,  7, 10],
     [10, 10,  6, 10,  9,  7,  11,   8,  9,  6],
     [6,   5, 10,  8,  7,  6,   4,  10,  7, 10],
     [5,  10,  9,  7,  6,  5,   8,   9, 10,  8],
     [5,   9,  8,  7,  6,  5,   9,  10,  9,  7]];       
Q  =  [[ 2,  4,  3,  1,  3],
       [ 9, 10,  7,  3,  9],
       [ 8,  5,  4,  8,  6],
       [10,  7,  6, 10,  7],
       [ 4,  6,  4,  8,  6],
       [10,  3,  6,  9,  8],
       [ 8, 10,  3,  5, 10], 
       [ 9,  6,  7,  7,  6], 
       [ 5,  3,  4,  5,  3], 
       [10,  3,  9,  6,  5], 
       [ 9,  6,  4,  3,  5], 
       [ 5,  5,  6,  6,  9], 
       [10,  7,  4,  3,  9], 
       [10,  3,  4,  3,  6], 
       [ 8,  8,  5, 10,  4], 
       [ 3, 10,  3,  4,  8], 
       [ 9,  7,  4,  4,  9], 
       [ 7,  6,  3,  9, 10], 
       [ 6,  9,  3,  8,  6], 
       [ 4,  4,  3,  5,  4], 
       [ 6,  6,  5,  5,  3], 
       [ 3,  7,  3,  5,  8], 
       [10,  7,  9,  5, 10], 
       [ 4,  4,  5,  7,  4], 
       [ 8,  9,  3,  9,  7]];                                
                                        
R   = [[ 6, 5, 5,10, 4],
       [10, 3, 8, 4, 5], 
       [ 8, 6, 9, 8, 9], 
       [ 5, 5,10, 7, 6], 
       [ 8, 4, 9, 3, 7], 
       [ 3, 3, 8, 4, 3], 
       [ 7, 9, 5, 5, 4], 
       [ 4, 6, 7, 7, 5], 
       [ 4, 6, 8, 5, 7], 
       [ 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 
       [ 7, 6, 7, 8, 7], 
       [ 6, 6, 5, 6, 6], 
       [ 7, 6, 9, 3, 7], 
       [ 5, 7, 7, 6, 7], 
       [ 4, 6, 6, 4, 8], 
       [ 7, 8, 6, 7, 3], 
       [ 9, 4, 8, 5, 3], 
       [ 3, 4, 3, 7, 3], 
       [ 5, 3, 3, 8, 3], 
       [ 6, 8, 4, 5, 7]];                                       
A   =   [12, 12, 13, 21, 22, 25, 27, 27, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 34, 35, 36, 36, 45, 46, 46, 51, 54, 54, 56, 58];                   
B   =   [72, 72, 73, 81, 82, 85, 87, 87, 89, 90, 92, 93, 94, 94, 95, 96, 96, 105, 106, 106, 111, 114, 114, 116, 118];                   
C   =   [20, 24, 25, 29, 35, 38, 42, 49, 55, 55, 57, 57, 57, 58, 62, 67, 68, 68, 69, 73];                   
D   =   [140, 144, 145, 149, 155, 158, 162, 169, 175, 175, 177, 177, 177, 178, 182, 187, 188, 188, 189, 193];
```

Comment: If your model is infeasible with the data you have, try solving with smaller data. Preferably data that you know is feasible. If you have a known solution, try adding constraints to force that solution and see if the model is OK or infeasible. You could also try the conflict refiner to see if that will show you what is infeasible.

Comment: float M=1000000;  is quite large. Have you tried with a smaller M ?